# What causes a controller function to be called in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm going through Angular tutorials and seeing code like this:

```
todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.todo = model;

    $scope.warningLevel = function() {
        return $scope.incompleteCount() < 3 ? "label-success" : "label-warning";
    }
});

<span ng-class="warningLevel()">Tasks</span>
```

Like magic, the span changes its class whenever calling warningLevel() would return a new value. But the tutorials don't explain why. I don't understand how Angular "knows" that warningLevel() would return a new value and needs to be called again. What is triggering warningLevel() to be called each time?

Comment: it called 2 way data binding https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding , in other words, every thing under a $scope will got update immediately on view whenever the model got changed.

Comment: @LinhPham but the view isn't just showing data from a model. It's showing the result of a function call. How does Angular know it has to call that function again?

Comment: It is pretty much the same, in javascript a variable can either be an object or a function. An object will return you value(s), a function with return statement will also return you a value. Check the answer below of @DonJuwe. And read the links included. :) ---- Edit: and it know to run the function because `()` in `ng-class` directy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Linh Pham pointed out this is the so called [Two-Way-Databinding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding). It works this way due to Angular's [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle.

> Processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children. Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the `$digest()` keeps calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing.

You can imagine it as a *static loop* which watches for changes and updates the values within the respective [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). You can also "hook" in to this cycle by binding`$watch`ers manually e.g.:

```
$scope.$watch('myScopeVar', function() {
    // do something
});
```